# How add parent for each slots in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying add parent span for each slot on my component, but it isn't working.

```
render(createElement) {
  return createElement('div', this.$slots.default.map(vnode => createElement('span', vnode)));
},
```

I want get html like below

```
<div>
  <span><img /></span>
  <span><img /></span>
  <span><img /></span>
</div>
```

but max what i can get it is

```
<div>
  <span>
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
  </span>
</div>
```

how fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
render(h){
  return h("div", this.$slots.default.map(v => {
    // eliminate returns, comments
    if (!v.tag)
      return v

    return h('span', [v])
  }))
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/VbrBMy?editors=1010).